# SSL_accept() Not Working

Tags: c, sockets, ssl, openssl, eof

I have researched for a while now, and didn't see my exact same problem anywhere. I'm just having a specific, quite simple problem: whenever my echo_server tries to run `SSL_accept()` function, it won't block the server waiting for a client to connect, function will just return 0, and if I go into `SSL_get_error()`, it will give me `SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL`, so I'm guessing the problem is, quoting from the manual, "an EOF was observed that violates the protocol."

Truth is I have no idea what does that mean, and it's getting really frustrating because I think I'm missing something very simple, but I don't know what.

Here's the code for my accept function (SSL_ctx previously initialized and socket opened):

```
SSL * sslconnection;

if((sslconnection = SSL_new(ctx)) == NULL){
    return NULL;
}

if(SSL_set_fd(sslconnection, socketd) != 1){
    return NULL;
}

if(SSL_accept(sslconnection) != 1){
    return NULL;
}

return sslconnection;
```

Also, I've tried to check my certificates with "openssl verify -verbose -purpose sslserver -CAfile 'CACertificate' 'ServerCertificate'", but it would say my Server Certificate is ok.

Any help is welcome, thanks in advance. Hope it's something really stupid and I'm just so obfuscated I can't see it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> whenever my echo_server tries to run SSL_accept() function, it won't block the server waiting for a client to connect

`SSL_accept` does not call `accept` for you. It expects that `accept` has already been called.

The correct sequence of calls is:

1. `socket`
2. `bind`
3. `listen`
4. `accept`
5. `SSL_new`
6. `SSL_set_fd`
7. `SSL_accept`

Download openssl sources from https://www.openssl.org/source/ and see demos/ssl/serv.cpp.

Comment: You save my life! How is it possible that, after calling accept() and the server is blocked, you can still do stuff like SSL_new(), etc.? Wouldn't it be blocked? Or that's the purpose? I mean, blocking it until a new connection is found and THEN executing the SSL part?

Comment: @DisplayName After `accept` returns you have a new client connection and the OS starts receiving data from the client (if any) in the background for you into the kernel socket buffer, that you will eventually read with `read`/`recv`/`recvmsg`.